# PDO MySQL like query not returning value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using a PDO to connect to a MySQL database. My query runs correctly and returns results as expected until I ad a 'like' at the end of the query in which no results are returned. I'm posting a mock query of my problem with just the trouble spot. Where am I going wrong with this?

```
$value = "text";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT something FROM table WHERE days LIKE "%:value%"');
$stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value));
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: [How can I use prepared statements with LIKE operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990965)

Comment: Don't know how I didn't see that when I searched for this... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$value = "text";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT something FROM table WHERE days LIKE :value');
$stmt->execute(array(':value' => "%".$value."%"));
```

Or

```
$value = "%text%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT something FROM table WHERE days LIKE :value');
$stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value));
```